# Why can't the default Ubuntu video player play MPEG4 movies without downloading additional codecs?

Tags: video, codecs, mp4

I know default video player in Ubuntu can download required codecs to
play MPEG4 files.

But I wonder why they are not embed this wide using codecs by default.

Suppose a user cannot access to Internet, how would they deal with this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, for playing MPEG4 and many decoding , it's necessary to install its codecs.

MPEG4 and many other video and audio decoding are need to install some packages like `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `ubuntu-restricted-addons` to play them perfectly.

Let us to look around this package:

```
apt show ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

The output has these lines in it:

> These software packages are from the Multiverse channel, restricted by copyright or legal issues in some countries. For more information, see http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/licensing

So as you see because of **copyright** or **legal issues** in **some countries** , it cannot be installed by default.

Many codecs and packages are those available in the `multiverse` repository of Ubuntu , that's not be enable by default, because of legal issues in some countries.

---

But you asked about condition that user cannot access to Internet.

In this condition the user who installed Ubuntu can check the *Install third party software* option during Ubuntu setup.

So many codecs are installed by default **without Internet** access.

Comment: Thank you for Advance answer, but although i check the Install third Party SW the  appropriate codecs for playing movies/sound as you said above NOT installed.

Comment: @EsmaeelE Thanks for your reply. I said "many codecs" but not "all of them". but if you haven't access to internet you can install codec's packages offline with this method : https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline